# What is the difference between of these two classes in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have a question what is the diffrence between **\Illuminate\Http\Request** and the **Request** classes in laravel 5. I've use the **\Illuminate\Http\Request** class for some ajax based thing in blade form.When using **\Illuminate\Http\Request** shows an error,

> Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

This is the codeblock what I've used

```
  Route::post('org_tree',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
         if(Request::ajax())
            {

            }
   });
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: The `Request` class is simply a [Laravel Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades) that wraps an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`. Facades are nothing more than syntactic sugar to grant you static access to the underlying class methods.

Answer (score 1):

the method ajax is not a static method and this class have no _callStatic magic method so you can use

```
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->ajax();
```

or use

```
\Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax();
```

Comment: Great ,I'll check this solution !

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the code using as below the problem resolved

```
Route::post('org_tree',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
     if($request->ajax())
        {
          //rest of the ajax body 
        }
});
```

or

```
Route::post('org_tree',function(Request $request)
{
     if($request->ajax())
        {
          //rest of the ajax body
        }
});
```

thats it!